# Код, проверяющий время и дату и возвращающий True, если время совпадает с указанным

Tags: python, telegram, бот, время

Я совсем новичок. Хотел бы написать бота для Telegram, который бы каждый день в определённое время присылал список дел. Написал программу, которая, по моему мнению, должна работать, но она не сработала.

Как лучше всего написать такой код? Как сделать  так, чтобы задача сама запускалась ежесекундно и проверяла время?

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

to_do = ['купить мыло и верёвку', 'починить стул']

now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

if current_time == '15:20:00':
    if len(to_do) != 0:
        print (*to_do)
```

Comment: Отправьте сначала свою реализацию, а мы попробуем вам помочь и указать где ошибка

Comment: Не прикрепилась сначала почему-то

Comment: Чтобы соблюдалось условие, проверка должна находиться цикле. Иначе проверяться, что время 15:20 будет только в момент запуска. лучше условие if засунуть в цикл while True и пусть каждую минуту проверяет, что время совпадает

Comment: и секунды проверять не надо, потому что если случится 15:20:01, то программа сегодня ничего не пришлет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

to_do = ['купить мыло и верёвку', 'починить стул']

while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    
    if current_time == '15:20':
        if len(to_do) != 0:
            print (to_do)
            
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: если пауза 60 секунд, то проверять секунды не надо. Будет 01 секунда, и всё, на сегодня ничего не случится.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, точно

Comment: @Эникейщик То есть он не каждую секунду проверяет актуальное время?

Comment: А как проверить, что код работает? запускаю его каждую секунду и список он не возвращает в указанное время(

Comment: если в коде есть пауза 60 секунд, то эти 60 секунд код ничего не делает

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо! А как понять, что он вообще его проверяет? Для этого не нужен отдельный цикл?